# How to cluster n-grams?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I just wanted to know how to cluster n-grams based on their semantics. Like clustering together n-grams that are semantically similar by leveraging the distributional hypothesis suggesting that similar words appear in similar contexts.

Comment: Please give more details about your setting: what kind of n-grams? are they extracted from a document where you could obtain their context? or do you have really long n-grams, enough to represent the semantics? generally semantics for a target word $w_i$ is obtained with the context window, e.g. $w_{i-n}...w_{i+n}$

Comment: Probably 1 gram (normal words in a paragraph which are a part of the document). Now I want to cluster those if they are semantically similar and I was thinking of `spectral clustering.`  If you have any suggestions on that? Also could you more elaborate on the context window? The main purpose is to reduce the dimensionality of vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Distributional semantics models are based on representing an instance with the words that represent its meaning. Typically if one is interested in representing the meaning of a word $w_i$ then the words that represent its meaning are the ones which appear close to it, e.g. withing a window of N words preceding/following it.

Example where $w_i$ is the target word with a window +/- 2:

$w_1,w_2,...,w_{i-3},\mathbf{w_{i-2},w_{i-1}},w_{i},\mathbf{w_{i+1},w_{i+2}},w_{i+3},...,w_N$

So the "meaning" of $w_i$ in this instance would be represented by the four words in the context window: $w_{i-2},w_{i-1},w_{i+1},w_{i+2}$. By collecting occurrences of $w_i$ everywhere in the document one obtains a set of contexts that can be used in different ways. For example one could build a context vector $a_1,...a_{|V|}$ over the vocabulary $V$ where each cell $a_k$ contains the frequency of $w_k \in V$ in the context of the target word. By applying the same process with different words, each word can be represented with its context vector and then various operations can be made on these vectors: similarity measures, clustering, etc.

Generally clustering based on words semantics is done with specific methods such as [Latent Semantics Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis).

In theory the method can be applied to any unit (e.g. n-grams), but more complex units require more data, more memory and more computing power.